Is it possible to display order number in Android's system photo picker?
When using Android's system photo picker as part of an app, I am only able to see the checkmarks on selection of photos. Is it possible to display the ordering number instead?
Using it like so: PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly)

No, it is not possible to show ordering number instead of checkmarks on selections to the photos. I have also checked by restricting the number of selection of photos (must be greater than one) and it still displayed the checkmark. Also, according to the google docs (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) there does not seem to be anything mentioned regarding updating the UI of the picker.
